# Why ansible's not definied variable not counts as a error for playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

With a simple playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug: var=not_existing_var
```

I got

```
ok: [compute01] => {
    "not_existing_var": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

And `ansible-playbook`'s exit code turns to 0. But why? Why is it `ok`? 
Is it normal when *any* undefined variables became defined this way?

And a second question: how can I workaround this and get my error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior. I can't explain why it is the way it is, the same way I cannot explain why it is handled differently in application X. It was a design decision by the developers. But I believe it is a good feature since you can in detail define what should happen with undefined variables with these two filters:

1. **mandatory**

   If a variable is required simply add the mandatory filter:

   ```
   not_existing_var | mandatory
   ```

   This will make Ansible immediately fail and complain about the missing variable.

   Docs: [Defining mandatory values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defining-mandatory-values)
2. **default**

   You can provide a default value in case the variable is not set like so:

   ```
   not_existing_var | default("the default value")
   ```

   Docs: [Providing default values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values)

If this behavior is uncomfortable and you want all undefined variables to cause an error, you can [define this in you `ansible.cfg`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_configuration.html#error-on-undefined-vars):

```
error_on_undefined_vars=True
```